Mapping enum class to function overload
Hi there I am facing the following problem: I have a class with many member functions of a certain pattern. Each of these member functions has 3 overloads and these overloads are the same for all member functions in consideration. By "same" I mean they have the same signature except for the function name. This leads to much code repetition in control states selecting the desired method. Which is nasty to maintain when new methods are added.
Moreover, I have a enum class (based on unsigned ints) with an item for each of these member functions.
What I try is to create a mapping from the enum class to the member functions (See example below).
Example
I have several member functions memfunc1, memfunc2, ... and I have 3 functions (say caller1, caller2, caller3) each taking the arguments of one of the three overloads plus an enum as argument which tells me which of the memfuncs to call. I want to avoid doing the mapping enum to memfunc three times instead of once. I can imagine this is possible since the compiler knows signatures because the overloads of each memfunc appear in separated control paths.
    enum class Algos : unsigned int {
    FUN1 = 0,
    FUN2,
    FUN3,
    NUM_OF_FUNCTIONS
};

    class Algorithms {
    Type1 memfunc1();
    Type1 memfunc1(const Type2&) const;
    Type1 memfunc1(Type3&, const Type2&);
    Type1 memfunc2();
    Type1 memfunc2(const Type2&) const;
    Type1 memfunc2(Type3&, const Type2&);
    Type1 memfunc3();
    Type1 memfunc3(const Type2&) const;
    Type1 memfunc3(Type3&, const Type2&);
    };

What I currently do is
Type1 Algorithms::caller1(Algos algo) {
  if (algo == Algos::FUN1) {
    return memfunc1();
  }
  if (algo == Algos::FUN2) {
    return memfunc2();
  }
  if (algo == Algos::FUN3) {
    return memfunc3();
  }
}

Type1 Algorithms::caller2(const Type2& arg, Algos algo) {
  if (algo == Algos::FUN1) {
    return memfunc1(arg);
  }
  if (algo == Algos::FUN2) {
    return memfunc2(arg);
  }
  if (algo == Algos::FUN3) {
    return memfunc3(arg);
  }
}

Type1 Algorithms::caller3(Type3& arg1, const Type2& arg2, Algos algo) {
  if (algo == Algos::FUN1) {
    return memfunc1(arg1, arg2);
  }
  if (algo == Algos::FUN2) {
    return memfunc2(arg1, arg2);
  }
  if (algo == Algos::FUN3) {
    return memfunc3(arg1, arg2);
  }
}

But I want to separate the mapping from the enums to the member function from the specific overload. Because yet all three caller functions do more or less the same:

FUN1 -> memfunc1 
FUN2 -> memfunc2 
FUN3 -> memfunc3 
...

in way which allows to call like:
    Type1 a = std::invoke(mapping(FUN1), const Type2&);

I'm not tied to exactly this syntax using std::invoke and it's also totally fine to provide the instance of Algorithms when calling, but I want the compiler to select the correct overload of the function based on the provided arguments. Ideally the mapping can be defined at compile time, since the enums and the provided arguments are known at compile time.
So far I read some related stack overflow posts including:

Storing functions from class in array and invoke them c++
Is it possible to hold member functions with different arguments in an array?
How can I select a specific function overload?

as well as many cppreference pages including https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn
My approach so far was creating an array
    using Overload2 = std::function<Type1(const Type2&)>;
    std::array<Overload2, std::to_underlying(Algos::NUM_OF_FUNCTIONS)> pMethods;

and then populating the array by calling
    pMethods.at(std::to_underlying(Algos::FUN1)) = [this](const Type2& var) {
    return memfunc1(var);
    };

and similar for other member functions and overloads. However, this is not a desired solution since it moves the code repetition to another part of the code, but does not resolves it.
They idea of using a std::unordered_map I discarded early in the process, because as far as I know this container does not work well with the constexpr keyword for it is non-literal type. I think I remember several SO-posts out there tackling this problem.
Using recent versions of c++ is fine for me as long as they compile in g++-14 and clang++-18. I'd prefer solutions using no libraries other than stl and prefer memory safe stl solutions over c-style ones.
Thanks in Advance!
Edit
In the moment I am too new on the platform to be allowed to upvote your answers, but I consider them all as helpful. Not only the one I'll mark as accepted.

A [mcve] would be good.

Is there a reason why you want to do this yourself, instead of using the mechanism for dynamic dispatch built into the core C++ language itself?

@user12002570 As I am asking for a Code design and not for a bug fix, a minimal reproducible example  would be a sufficient answer to my question. Thus I have none. But I can provide a more verbose description of my use case.

A [mre] isn't something for debugging only. It's a small illustration of your problem that works as it does for you, and we can refactor to test our solution. Otherwise, it will become a game of guessing and shifting goalposts that will only serve to waste a lot of time.

@Eljay No there is no reason. If you see how dynamic dispatch solves the problem, you are welcome to share how. However dynamic dispatch does not sound like something working at compile time to me.

It probably can be solved with macros, but that would be a C style solution. You definitely want to keep the member functions and their three variants in the same class? Otherwise there could be more possibilities for tackling this.

Or have a fourth general template function variant within the class for each member function?

... does not sound like something working at compile time to me.  I do not understand what you mean here.

@Sebastian "Or have a fourth general template function variant within the class for each member function?" Sounds clean. I would appreciate your answer. Moving member functions from the Algorithms class into a derived class is fine as well.

@Eljay Dynamic dispatch happens at runtime according to wikipedias definition. In my case there is no need to do this at run time since all required info is present at compile time.

@user-1 then give your functions different names, rather than an enum parameter. Unless you want to pick algo at runtime, i.e. dynamic dispatch

Your function is doing dynamic dispatch, at run time.

Maybe I wasn't clear about that. The mapping is desired to be fixed at compile time, but not the argument the program is mapping. And the question asks for a clean way to write down this map.

You can have a single array for each caller member, in a template function.
class Algorithms {
    Type1 memfunc1() { return 1; }
    Type1 memfunc1(const Type2&) { return 1; }
    Type1 memfunc1(Type3&, const Type2&) { return 1; }
    Type1 memfunc2() { return 2; }
    Type1 memfunc2(const Type2&) { return 2; }
    Type1 memfunc2(Type3&, const Type2&) { return 2; }
    Type1 memfunc3() { return 3; }
    Type1 memfunc3(const Type2&) { return 3; }
    Type1 memfunc3(Type3&, const Type2&) { return 3; }
        
    template<typename... Args>
    Type1 caller(Algos algo, Args... args) {
        static constexpr std::array<Type1(Algorithms::*)(Args...), std::to_underlying(Algos::NUM_OF_FUNCTIONS)> dispatch = { &Algorithms::memfunc1, &Algorithms::memfunc2, &Algorithms::memfunc3 };
        return std::invoke(dispatch[std::to_underlying(algo)], this, args...); 
    }
        
public:
    Type1 caller1(Algos algo) { 
        return caller<>(algo);
    }
    Type1 caller2(const Type2& arg, Algos algo) { 
        return caller<const Type2&>(algo, arg);
    }
    Type1 caller3(Type3& arg1, const Type2& arg2, Algos algo) { 
        return caller<Type3&, const Type2&>(algo, arg1, arg2);
    }
};


This (the edited version) looks nice. I' will transfer this to my example and will be back with feedback. By the way is it possible to replace Algorithms::* by a std::functional expression?

Is it possible to adapt this example to the case where an overload of the member functions is const?

@user-1 you'd need a const qualified version of caller, and the array would be of Type1(Algorithms::*)(Args...) const, but it's otherwise the same

template<auto x>
using val_t = std::integral_constant<decltype(x), x>;

template<auto x>
constexpr val_t<x> val_k = {};

these are values as types and monostates.  This is useful in that you can convert enums to variants with it.
template<auto...Xs>
using venum_t = std::variant< val_t<Xs>... >;

a venum_t is a variant over a list of values as monostates.
using vAlgos = venum_t<Algos::FUN1, Algos::FUN2, Algos::FUN3>;

vAlgos is a venum wrapper around the enum Algos.  We can automate generating it (using Algos::NUM_OF_FUNCTIONS and assuming contiguity).
At runtime, vAlgos is an integer whose value happens to correspond to the Algos enum runtime value (0, 1, 2).  But we can use std::apply to get the value as a compile time constant!  What more, we can convert run time values to compile time values like this:
template<class E, E... Xs, class R=venum_t<Xs...> >
R make_venum( E x ) {
  using f_t = R(*)();
  f_t table[] = {
    +[]()->R {
      return R(std::in_place_type_t<val_t<Xs>>{});
    }...
  };
  return table[ std::underlying_type_t<E>(x) ]();
}

now
vAlgos make_vAlgos( Algos a ) {
  return make_venum<Algos, Algos::FUN1, Algos::FUN2, Algos::FUN3>( a );
}

takes a runtime Algos value and produces a variant over compile-time monostates.  (Writing this function can also be automated, I'm writing it manually here to keep it simple).
What do we get out of all of this noise?
template<Algos algo, class...Ts>
auto memfunc_caller(val_t<algo>, Ts&&...ts) {
  if constexpr (algo == Algos::FUN1) {
    return memfun1(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  } else if constexpr (algo == Algos::FUN2) {
    return memfun2(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  } else if constexpr (algo == Algos::FUN3) {
    return memfun3(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};

we then do
template<class...Ts>
Type1 Algorithms::caller( vAlgos valgo, Ts&&... ts ) {
  return std::visit([&](auto algo){
    return memfunc_caller(algo, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }, valgo);
}

template<class...Ts>
Type1 Algorithms::caller( Algos algos, Ts&&... ts ) {
  return caller( make_vAlgos(algos), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}

note that passing around vAlgos instead of Algos saves a bit of conversion work.
We can simplify this down to 1 or 2 functions if you don't want the full power of variants over enums.

I'd recomment to organize like this:
class Algorithm
{
public:
    virtual Type1 memfunc() = 0;
    virtual Type1 memfunc(const Type2&)  = 0;....
};
class Algorithm1: public Algorithm
{
public:
    virtual Type1 memfunc();
    virtual Type1 memfunc(const Type2&); ....
};
class Algorithm2: public Algorithm
{
public:
    virtual Type1 memfunc();
    virtual Type1 memfunc(const Type2&); ....
};
...

...
class Algorithms
{
...
    // static just for simplicity, not required really
    static Algoritm argorithms[3] = {new Algorithm1(), new Algoritm2(), ...};
//wrap und encapsulate
};

The idea is to call like this
Algos algo = FUN1;
Type1 x = Algoritms::alborithms[algo]->memfunc(...);


If you break up the class into smaller bits, representing individual algorithms, then you can leverage a std::variant for much of the machinery (which is constexpr friendly), and keep your own switch localized.
class Algorithms;
struct Algo1 {
    Type1 memfunc(Algorithms*);
    Type1 memfunc(Algorithms*, const Type2&);
    Type1 memfunc(Algorithms*, Type3&, const Type2&);
};

struct Algo2 {
    Type1 memfunc(Algorithms*);
    Type1 memfunc(Algorithms*, const Type2&);
    Type1 memfunc(Algorithms*, Type3&, const Type2&);
};

// ...

class Algorithms {
    using Impl = std::variant<Algo1, Algo2, ...>;
    static constexpr Impl ImplForAlgo(Algos a) {
        switch(a) {
          case Algos::FUN1: return Impl(std::in_place_index<0>);
          case Algos::FUN2: return Impl(std::in_place_index<1>);
          case Algos::FUN3: return Impl(std::in_place_index<2>);
        }
        throw std::bad_variant_access();
    }

public:
    Type1 caller1(Algos algo) { 
        return std::visit<Type1>([this](auto&& a){
            return a.memfunc(this);
        }, ImplForAlog(algo))
    }
    Type1 caller2(const Type2& arg, Algos algo) { 
        return std::visit<Type1>([this, &arg](auto&& a){
            return a.memfunc(this, arg);
        }, ImplForAlog(algo))
    }
    Type1 caller3(Type3& arg1, const Type2& arg2, Algos algo) { 
        return std::visit<Type1>([this, &arg1, &arg2](auto&& a){
            return a.memfunc(this, arg1, arg2);
        }, ImplForAlog(algo))
    }

};


I passed Algorithms* explicitly in case any state from the old monolith is needed in individual algorithms. But if not, the resulting code is even more concise.
